# while loop is not working in shell script

Tags: shell, while-loop

Wednesday, May 21, 2014 10:09 AM
I am running below two programs

**first program:**

```
while read line

do 

if (cat /etc/passwd | grep -w ^"userid")
then
echo $line
fi
done < serverlist
```

**output:**

```
userid:kjhfkjshd:hjgf:hsgdf:hsgbdf
server1
userid:kjhfkjshd:hjgf:hsgdf:hsgbdf
server2
```

**second program:**

```
while read line
do
if ( sudo /bin/ssh $line /bin/cat /etc/passwd | grep -w ^"userid" )
then
echo $line
fi
done < serverlist
```

**OUTPUT**

```
userid:kjhfkjshd:hjgf:hsgdf:hsgbdf
server1
```

it is not going to check second server. i am not able to find what is wrong in second program. first program is fine. can anybody help me please?

Comment: i tried with adding echo $line under while read line. it is reading the second line. it is taking the first line from file serverlist properly. it is not taking the second line.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common perceived "problem" when using `ssh` in a loop. The root cause is that, when `ssh` is spawned the first time, it consumes the rest of your input, so on the second iteration of your loop, it finds that there is nothing to do and terminates.

The way to get around this is to feed `/dev/null` to `ssh` as input, either by doing `ssh -n ...` or a more explicit `ssh ... < /dev/null`.